# "Foreign key contraint" error message although there are no foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to change the engine for my table "adverts". It does not let me and I get the message that "a foreign key contraint fails". But I removed all foreign keys and SHOW CREATE TABLE gives me this:

```
CREATE TABLE `adverts` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_users` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `id_categories_adverts` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `duration` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `headline` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `description` text NOT NULL,
 `show_contact` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `stamp_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `stamp_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Why can't I change the engine of my table? I am using

> ALTER TABLE adverts ENGINE=MyISAM

Comment: Is there another table having a foreign key to your adverts table?

Comment: You are welcome. I have added this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is at least another table with foreign key to your `adverts` table. You need to tackle with those foreign key constraints, possibly, by temporarily/permanently removing them.